# Jquery dialog window not rendering correctly

Tags: jquery, dialog

When I include my jquery dialog div on my page, the html markup of the dialog renders at the bottom of the page instead of being hidden until the user triggers the open event.  Also, the remaining parts of my page do not load.

Here is the code of my dialog div:

```
    <div id="photoAdd_dialog" title="Upload Photos">
    <form name="photoInfo_form" action="" method="post" id="photoInfo_form">
       ...html markup for several input fields...
     </form>
   </div>

   <script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){
 $("#photoAdd_dialog").dialog(
               {autoOpen: false,
                   width: 400,
                   resizable: false,
                   modal: true}
 );
 //end of the dialog setting
 $("#reminder").css("display","none");

 });
//end of preload
    .... form validation javascript here
 </script>
```

What I've done:

- Made sure the jquery css and js files are up to date and pointing to the right location
- Included a different jquery dialog on this page and it worked perfectly fine..i.e. was hidden till user clicks a link to trigger the dialog.

Totally stuck on this.  Appreciate any help!  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using jQuery UI for the dialog?  Is the JS file linked properly?

Secondly, if your page is not loading AT ALL you probably have an error being thrown.  Use Chrome Dev Tools or Firebug to see the JS console output.

Where are you triggering the Dialog to open?

All you need to initialize the dialog is:

```
//Auto opens by default
$("#photoAdd_dialog").dialog()

//To open the dialog
$("#photoAdd_dialog").dialog('open')

//To close the dialog
$("#photoAdd_dialog").dialog('close')
```

jQuery should hide the dialog once initialized, therefore you don't need that CSS manipulation.

All in all, I would do this:

```
//link to JS files here

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#photoAdd_dialog").dialog(
        {
            autoOpen: false,
            width: 400,
            resizable: false,
            modal: true,
            title: "Upload Photos",
        });
    });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".opener").onClick(function(e){
        //stops the click from changing the page and whatever other default action would happen.
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#photoAdd_dialog").dialog('open');
    });

    $(".closer").onClick(function(e){
        //stops the click from changing the page and whatever other default action would happen.
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#photoAdd_dialog").dialog('close');
    });
</script>
```

//end of head and start of body

```
<div id="photoAdd_dialog">
    ...html markup for several input fields...
</div>

//I prefer classes, since IDs tie up namespace.  Not totally relevant for a small JS application though.
<a href="#" class="opener">Open Photo Add Dialog</a>

<a href="#" class="closer">Close Photo Add Dialog</a>
```

Make sure to checkout the jQuery UI demo pages: http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal

Happy coding!

Comment: Hi Jonathan - thanks for the detailed response.  I used a different jquery dialog box on the same page and it worked fine.  So, the JS files are linked properly I believe. It looks like there are a few errors being thrown in the console so I think thats where I should start.  I haven't used firebug or chrome console debugger yet (novice!)...but found a few resources on how to use the tool...so will do that and update you guys.  thx again.

Comment: I'm getting this in the error console for line 1 of my file.  However there is nothing there.  My doctype declaration starts at line 3       1Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )

Answer (score 0):

Should

```
$("#reminder").css("display","none");
```

really be

```
$("#photoAdd_dialog").css("display","none");
```

Or ...

What if you just put `style="display: none;"` inline and not worry about changing with jQuery, since that's the default you want anyway?

Comment: Hi Scott - the #reminder was for the form validation.  I've tried putting inline css to not display the dialog - which does that, BUT the rest of the page does not render.  Somehow something is booting the execution of the rest of the page... is my guess..?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using jQuery UI then there is a great helper css class built in just modify your div to this:

```
<div id="photoAdd_dialog" title="Upload Photos" class="ui-helper-hidden">
```

ALl this does is apply the `display:none` through a class in the css.  This is nice since it keeps out inline style statements, though many feel that `style="display:none;"` is okay, it depends on who you talk to.

Comment: Alexander - good tip, thx.  That does hide the dialog on page load, BUT unfortunately the dialog does not open on user click...and the remainder of the page (e.g. footer div) does not render.  So basically its exiting somehow when I include this div - not sure why and where.  Anyone hv other ideas?  As you can tell I'm a new developer:)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the offending piece of code.  Turns out nothing to do w/ JS/jquery.  Inside my dialog window I had this code that was retrieving data for my input field.  I had this code commented out.  Once I removed this, the dialog window works perfectly.  Still don't know why this would cause the issue, but here is the code:

```
               <!-- <?php $em=getAllEm();?> 
<?php foreach($em as $e):?>
    <option value="<?=$e[0]?>"><?php echo $e[1];?></option>
<?php endforeach;?> -->
```

I appreciate everyone's help!

Comment: Even though you may have this commented out for browser render, the server still parses the php code, so chances are you had a bug which was causing an error and breaking the dialog box. You have to comment out the php code as well, so it becomes: `<!-- <?php //$em=getAllEm() ?> -->`